# IE9 filling textboxes with carriage returns

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue where I have a textbox that gets populated via ajax. it's filled with an array of data that is delimited by carriage returns (\r\n).

This works perfectly in ff, chrome, etc. However in IE9 the carriage return delimiters do nothing.

Example.. in FF and Chrome:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

in IE9:

```
ABCDE
```

any ideas?

**EDIT:** This is using jqGrid. The data gets automatically populated via that. When i set the page to IE9 mode, the textbox does contain the carriage returns.

Comment: How do IE7 and IE8 perform on this? Does IE9s Compat View(s) make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this is just a weird quirk in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Does this [sample at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/izuqe4/) work for you? I realize you're using AJAX, but how are you actually setting the value of the textbox?

I've used a `<textarea>`, and it works in Firefox, and all combinations of compatibility settings in IE9.

```
$("#foo").val("A\r\nB\r\nc\r\nD\r\nE\r\nF");

<textarea id="foo" rows=10></textarea>
```

Comment: I had exactly the same 'quirk', but was appending, rather than setting the value. The line/carriage returns worked fine once I use .val().